# Dividing 100 pens among 5 children, everyone gets an odd number of pens: possible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I want to divide 100 pens among 5 children in a way that each of them gets an odd number of pens.
I think it's not possible but what is the answer and why?

Tag's may be wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: What do you get when you add an odd number with an odd number? And then add another odd number? If you do this five times, you'll see that it isn't possible.

Comment: "logic" as a tag here refers to the sub discipline of mathematics which is, roughly, about the application of formal logic to mathematics. The tag should not be used to indicate "reasoning", as it seems to be doing here.

Comment: There is a joke answer.  Give four of the children 1 pen each and the last of them 96.  96 is certainly an odd number of pens to have.

Comment: 96 is an odd number of sugar cubes it put in your tea, but it's an utterly reasonable number of pens to have in my opininion.  I used to do odd jobs.  I have to play a flute to soothe an insomniac hippopotamus.

Answer (score 5):

The sum of 5 odd numbers is odd and cannot be equal to 100 that is even

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- Odd + Odd = Even
- Even + Odd = Odd
- Even + Even = Even

Using these pieces, is the sum of five odds even or odd?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you distributed $100$ pens among $5$ children, so that everyone got an odd number of pens. But addition of $5$ odd numbers gives you an odd number. Thus, adding them back could not give you $100$, since $100$ is even. Thus, by contradiction, you could not have distributed $100$ pens among $5$ children so that every child got an odd number of pens.

Answer (score 1):

An even number $e$ has remainer $0$ when we divided by $2$. We say,

$$e \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$

Keep in mind that in mod $2$ , $x+2k$ where $k$ is an integer means the same as $x$. More generally, $n \pmod k$ means the remainder when we divide $n$ by $k$ (which is equivalent to) plus or minus some integer multiple of $n$.

An odd number on the other hand has remainder $1$:

$$o \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

There is a rule which say that if $x \equiv a \pmod c$ and $y \equiv b \pmod c$ then:

$$x+y \equiv a+b \pmod c$$

Which is not hard to prove. Therefore we have that the sum of $5$ odd numbers in modulo $2$ is:

$$1+1+1+1+1 \equiv 5 \equiv 1+2(2) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

Thus the sum of $5$ odd numbers is always an odd number.